# Page visibility when resizing

Tags: javascript, css, webview, html

I am creating a webpage and when I resize the window it kind of starts to mess up. Text changes its position and so on. How is it possible to keep it beautiful even after resizing the window? Maybe there are some video courses? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Look into a responsive grid system, such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). (It uses [media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50936442/712526) under the hood, but gives an easier-to-use interface.)

Comment: BTW, if you provide an [MCVE], you might get an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

lots of video courses are available. You can search by "Responsive layouts" keyword. But you can get rid of easily. All you need is standard media queries. Put this media queries in the end of your .css file and start styling according to your screen size. (e.g for mobile size use (max-width : 767px) etc..)

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 979px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `css media-queries` it is a broad subject. So I can not point to exact destination to go. But the are tons of material on youtube pertaining those subject. You could also tried https://scrimba.com/ for interactive tutorial.

Comment: see this tag [media-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/media-queries) for related question

Answer (score 0):

CSS media queries can help. They let you make rules in CSS about how you want different elements on your webpage to display when the screen size changes, or when it is displayed on a smaller or larger screen to begin with. Here is a good introduction: [w3schools: CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

Basically, you set "breakpoints" and the styles you want for those breakpoints:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    body {
        margin: 10px;
    }
}
```

More examples: [w3schools: CSS Media Queries - Examples](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)